# Where does OpenTelemetry store it's collected data?

Tags: open-telemetry

Since OpenTelemetry documentation is quite young it doesn't properly elaborate where the data is stored and in which format and if we can manipulate it with a 3rd party.

To avoid diving into the source code in github and trying to figure it out by reading functions I figured I'd ask here.

Does anyone have any idea where does it store it's data and in which format?

Reading the data via Prometheus it shows to me in JSON format, but I'm not certain if it is either Prometheus who transforms it into JSON or if it is the OpenTelemetry that does it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenTelemetry doesn't store any data (traces, metrics, logs). It has concept of exporters, where data are exported to user selected data (trace, metric, log) storage (3rd party). OpenTelemetry is "middle layer", where you can switch to another storage easily.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says, OpenTelemetry instrumentation doesn't store the data anywhere. However, it does transmit it in [OTLP format](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otlp/) and I think that's the json you're seeing.

As an aside, there are also places where OpenTelemetry *does* store data, mostly in OpenTelemetry Collector. These are known as storage extensions, but probably aren't relevant to this question: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/extension/storage/filestorage

Comment: Interesting! I'll read more once I get some free time. Thanks.